How can I set the derivation path for a multisig across BlueWallet, Electrum and Sparrow wallet?
I just exported a PSBT from BlueWallet and now I'm trying to sign it with the final signature in a multisig setup in Electrum or Sparrow wallet however with both, I am unable to do so:
From my understanding, if I use the sign tool that both these wallets have, and I enter the address that corresponds to the private key needed to finalize the PSBT as well as the PSBT in base64 format, I will be left with a valid raw Bitcoin transaction that I can then broadcast. I MAY BE WRONG ABOUT THIS
Every time I enter the address into the address field, it says "Address is not in this wallet." I believe that this is because the wallets are stuck on a specific derivation path (I looked at the PSBT and the first signer was using the key at m/48'/0'/0'/2'/0/0). Right now, both wallets have a field in settings called Derivation and they are set to m/84'/0'/0' however they are immutable. Anyone know how I can access the 48' part of my wallet? Also, is there any other, better way to sign PSBTs other than doing it manually (if that even works; I am unsure).

I noticed that the path I provided (m/48'/0'/0'/2'/0/0) probably wasn't the path the original signer used. So, from a raw PSBT, how am I supposed to be able to tell which key my wallet should fetch?:
Here's the first half of the PSBT, other half is below:
bBdRZRnAAAAAAAA/////5b6HZFPowozK4ps94NruNKN8cEWntjKrMYoAbRw8i8SAAAAABcWABTAVE+CixByIjfP3qpusoZjvG9hhf/////fQpaZs3N5rivgY++9EPZdigPSCJAOevWeunuviTHatgAAAAAA/////0Kld37OKBDSpOWc48V15ibII74Ugwfow0cY8hYZDO75AAAAAAD/////FdgEE2oNr5DetpIhv4pHG700MV+45OTetoRN3pFRfSsAAAAAAP////+Dr6eKUhBCEK2+0uLiatsvRC/7aCM0clsaQ1n0mUxNdwAAAAA

A/////+luPasbW0PVvGpMp3d5NwYpqog6FiJxBIRnp8An2ShAAwAAAAD/////TEe/3WWPu96yEYZFOuRnuo2S2nWcPFyoez9XbRxxSAIAAAAAAP////9q0YFdD3uVTkW8k94jaJwJalqKDFzzUjzaeBXuZcS1egcAAAAA/////2rRgV0Pe5VORbyT3iNonAlqWooMXPNSPNp4Fe5lxLV6CAAAAAD/////atGBXQ97lU5FvJPeI2icCWpaigxc81I82ngV7mXEtXoKAAAAAP////9q0YFdD3uVTkW8k94jaJwJalqKDFzzUjzaeBXuZcS1eg0AAAAA/////2rR

Hi Myles, I updated the title to form a question. Please feel free to roll back my changes or further edit the title if I didn’t quite gather the gist of your topic. Perhaps it would be helpful to first create a multisig only using one wallet to learn how each operates in a multisig setup to reduce the sources of possible interaction issue as you work towards a multi-software setup.

First, the public key between BlueWallet and SparrowWallet is different, so if you create a psbt in your BlueWallet, it can not be signed in the Sparrow wallet(because of the different private key). Thus, you can create a psbt with your public key generated by your Sparrow wallet, then load the psbt in base64 format, so that you can sign with your private key(generated in the sparrow wallet).

It's a different key because I'm using 2 of 3 multisig. I built the multisig wallet using three HD wallets in BlueWallet and now, I am trying to do the following:
Partially sign the transaction in BlueWallet with one of their keys (done)
Send the PSBT to my Sparrow Wallet that holds one of the HD wallets included in the multisig (done)
Sign the PSBT fully using the SparrowWallet wallet - (not done, I don't know which private key corresponds to the PSBT and I don't know how to fully sign a PSBT in SparrowWallet)

I advise you to try to build the multisig wallet with all sparrow wallets, and sign the psbt again because I guess that the BIPs the BlueWallet used may be different from the SparrowWallet.(Don't send from BlueWallet to SparrowWallet)
